# Different constructor calls depending on compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rvalue-reference

Running the code supplied in this question:

[Why move return an rvalue reference parameter need to wrap it with std::move()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187715/why-move-return-an-rvalue-reference-parameter-need-to-wrap-it-with-stdmove)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class TD;

class Widget {
public:
    explicit Widget(const std::string& name) : name(name) {
        std::cout << "Widget created with name: " << name << ".\n";
    }

    Widget(const Widget& w) : name(w.name) {
        std::cout << "Widget " << name << " just got copied.\n";
    }

    Widget(Widget&& w) : name(std::move(w.name)) {
        std::cout << "Widget " << name << " just got moved.\n";
    }

private:
    std::string name;
};

Widget passThroughMove(Widget&& w) {
    // TD<decltype(w)> wType;
    // TD<decltype(std::move(w))> mwType;
    return std::move(w);
}

Widget passThrough(Widget&& w) {
    return w;
}

int main() {
    Widget w1("w1");
    Widget w2("w2");

    Widget wt1 = passThroughMove(std::move(w1));
    Widget wt2 = passThrough(std::move(w2));

    return 0;
}
```

Yields different results depending on the compiler I use. When compiling using the latest Visual Studio (tried both C++14 and C++17) I get the following results:

```
Widget created with name: w1.
Widget created with name: w2.
Widget w1 just got moved.
Widget w2 just got moved. //<---
```

Ran and compiled this code online and the results were different. In the provided question the user also receives the same results:

```
Widget created with name: w1.
Widget created with name: w2.
Widget w1 just got moved.
Widget w2 just got copied. //<---
```

Why is w2 being moved when using Visual Studio and copied when using various different compilers?

Comment: A question should be self contained. The linked question could be deleted.

Comment: This happens mostly because msvc (the compiler that vs uses by default) is using different implementations that are not standard for many of it's functions/classes. A good example of this is std::exception, which for many compilers is an object that doesn't do pretty much anything, but in msvc it can take as parameter for it's constructor a string and also has a .what() function which allows printing it. I am not sure if this is the case here too, but it most likely is. Correct me if i'm wrong because i'm curious about it too!

Comment: @GhostyFrosty in this particular case, MSVC has simply beat both Clang and GCC to implement [P1825R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1825r0.html), as of MSVC v19.24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### MSVC has implemented P1825R0 - More implicit moves

As can be seen in the [Microsoft C++ language conformance table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019) section of the Visual Studio C++ documentation, this is Visual Studio implementing

- [P1825R0: Merged wording for P0527R1 and P1155R3 (more implicit moves)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1825r0.html),

as of  [Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.4), compiler MSVC version 19.24.

The essential parts of P1825R0 has been added to [[class.copy.elision]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.elision#3) [**emphasis** mine]:

> An *implicitly movable entity* is a variable of automatic storage
> duration that is either a non-volatile object or an rvalue reference
> to a non-volatile object type. In the following copy-initialization
> contexts, **a move operation might be used instead of a copy
> operation:**
>
> - (3.1) If the *expression* in a `return` ([stmt.return]) or `co_­return` ([stmt.return.coroutine]) statement is a (possibly
>   parenthesized) *id-expression* that names **an implicitly movable
>   entity declared in the body or *parameter-declaration-clause* of the
>   innermost enclosing function** or lambda-expression, or
> - (3.2) ...
>
> overload resolution **to select the constructor for** the copy or
> **the `return_­value`** overload to call **is first performed as if the expression or operand were an rvalue**. [...].

Using [godbolt.ms](https://www.godbolt.ms/), and the following contrived example

```
#include <memory>

struct Foo {
    Foo(int num) : num(num) {}
    Foo(const Foo& f) : num(f.num) {}
    Foo(Foo&& f) : num(std::move(f.num)) {}
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = delete;
    int num;
};

Foo maybeConsumeMyPreciousFoo(Foo&& foo, bool consume_foo) {
    if (consume_foo) { return std::move(foo); }
    else { return foo; }  // "Should not move" (as we'll see this is an invalid assumption)
}
```

we can inspect, in particular, the generated assemby of the line `else { return foo; }` in the `maybeConsumeMyPreciousFoo(...)` function;

for MSVC v19.23:

```
mov     rdx, QWORD PTR foo$[rsp]
mov     rcx, QWORD PTR __$ReturnUdt$[rsp]
call    Foo::Foo(Foo const &)             ; Foo::Foo
mov     rax, QWORD PTR __$ReturnUdt$[rsp]
```

and for MSVC v19.24:

```
mov     rdx, QWORD PTR foo$[rsp]
mov     rcx, QWORD PTR __$ReturnUdt$[rsp]
call    Foo::Foo(Foo &&)       ; Foo::Foo
mov     rax, QWORD PTR __$ReturnUdt$[rsp]
```

respectively, showing that the branch, for the latter version, actually moves from the `foo` parameter as if it was an rvalue.

---

#### GCC and Clang are yet to implement P1825R0

GCC:

> #### [C++ Standards Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html):
>
> [...]
>
> #### C++2a Language Features
>
> [...]
>
> **DR: More implicit moves (merge P0527R1 and P1155R3)**
>
> Available in GCC?: No
>
> - [Bug 91427 - Implement P1825R0, Merged wording for P0527R1 and P1155R3](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91427)

Clang:

> #### [C++ Support in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)
>
> [...]
>
> ###C++20 implementation status
>
> P1825R0 not even listed.

Finally, [cppreference's *C++ compiler support* page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) also lists P1825R0 as non-supported for both Clang and GCC.