# Why doesn't automatic move work with function which return the value from rvalue reference input?

Tags: c++, copy-elision

I already know automatic move is not woking with the function which return value from Rvalue Reference input. But why?

Below is example code which automatic move is not working with.

```
Widget makeWidget(Widget&& w) {
  ....
  return w; // Compiler copies w. not move it.
}
```

If the function input is from copy by value, automatic move works.

```
Widget makeWidget(Widget w) {
  ....
  return w; // Compiler moves w. not copy it.
}
```

Comment: move is not copy elision.

Comment: @appleapple This example is not RVO or NRVO. But compiler can optimize copy operation to move operation. So can't I call it copy elision?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187776/5980430  (although it looks like c++20 have change the rule as @songyuanyao 's answer shows.

Comment: @appleapple Thanks for your comment. But my point is I already know this compiler behavior but why?  Accepting  this rvalue automatic move operation from c++20 means that many people just have same thought with me. Move optimization of above example seems straight forward but why c++ can't accept this till c++20 ?

Comment: @OP in case it's unclear, I was linking to @ Yakk 's answer which contains some explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant part of the C++17 standard [[class.copy.elision/3]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.elision#3):

> In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation might be used instead of a copy operation:
>
> - If the expression in a `return` statement is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that **names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or parameter-declaration-clause** of the innermost enclosing function...

This does not hold for:

```
Widget makeWidget(Widget&& w)
{
  return w;
}
```

since `w` does not name an object with automatic storage duration (within the function).

In C++20, the situation [is different](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.copy.elision#3):

> An *implicitly movable entity* is a **variable of automatic storage duration** that is either a non-volatile object or an **rvalue reference to a non-volatile object type**. In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation might be used instead of a copy operation:
>
> - If the expression in a `return` or `co_­return` statement is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that **names an implicitly movable entity declared in the body or parameter-declaration-clause** of the innermost enclosing function...

Here, the reference `w` satisfies those requirements since it is an rvalue reference declared in the parameter-declaration-clause.

Why the same was not until C++20? I cannot say; likely nobody proposed such a change before.

Answer (score 5):

The code should work as you expected since C++20; automatic move operation is performed when [returning](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters) local variables and parameters, and it works for rvalue reference too (since C++20).

> If expression is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names a
> variable whose type is either
>
> - a non-volatile object type or
> - a non-volatile rvalue reference to object type (since C++20)

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iOJr4JntYXwWtxhG)

Comment: Wow, you means that compiler will automatically moves w  from c++ 20. But why is this not a c++ spec until now? It seems very straight forward optimization point.

Comment: @myoldgrandpa I'm not sure, it might be just a miss in C++11, and recovered in C++20.

Comment: I edit my question. copy elision -> automatic move

Comment: I have tested above code with g++ --std=c++20, but automatic move is not working.  Maybe compiler issue?

Comment: @myoldgrandpa I tested with gcc [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iIGNEyYn73OfZByh) and seems working fine.

Comment: @myoldgrandpa • Which version of `g++`?  11.2.0?  12.0 (pre-release stage 3)?